Use Boltzmann policy in Pytorch
I have a tensor with one dimension like
tensor([1., 1., 3.])

How can I trans this tensor using the Boltzmann policy?

There is only a "nn.Softmax" in pytorch, but its distribution has no temperature parameter.


nn.Softmax(dim=0)(x / tem)
